# Getting iReport working with Maven and Netbeans 8

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, ireport, netbeans-8

Trying to build a report in Netbeans 8 using Maven - all components downloaded in the last week so versions are latest in all cases.

Setup:

- Netbeans 8 with multiple JDKs (not just JDK8)

  `maven.compiler.source/target=1.7`
- Jasperreports 3.5.3 dependency.
- iReport plugin.
- Some simple `jrxml` reports that work fine in JasperSoft Studio 5.6.0

---

I have two primary issues:

1. The `iReport` plugin, when `preview` is selected insists on building the `jasper` files in the same folder as the `jrxml` files. This is clearly against the Maven ethos. There is an option on the "Compilation and Execution" tab of the iReport configuration that suggests it allows you to change the target folder but I cannot find any way of putting anything meaningful in there. Relative paths fail, absolute paths are ignored.
2. If I leave the target folder alone and just hit preview I get an exception that suggests it is using Java 8 to compile the report (use of the new `LocalDateTime` when referring to `Timestamp`):

   ```
   ...
   Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
   Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
   1. The type java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be resolved.
   It is indirectly referenced from required .class files                 
   value = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1980-01-01 00:00:00"); //$JR_EXPR_ID=3$
           <----------------------------------------------->
   ```

   I am using the maven `jasperreports-plugin` to build the reports and they correctly arrive in `target\jasper` - if only I can make the iReport plugin to refer to the jasper files there instead of building them itself I could make progress.

Comment: There is no reason for a plugin to behave as Maven expects.

Comment: @JamesB - Could you perhaps explain why? If the target path configuration worked it could certainly integrate perfectly so long as I can configure a relative path - which the default configuration of "." implies that I can.